# I've gotten an error telling me, "expected initializer before 'digitalWrite'"

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I should mention that I didn't write this code but got it from [HERE](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Aritra_B/obstacle-avoiding-robot-car-b38334?ref=search&ref_id=robot%20car&offset=23).

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo myservo; // create a servo object
int redled=13; // declare the pins
int greenled=12;

int servopin=9;
int trigpin=6;
int echopin=5;
float distance;
float duration;
int datapin=7;
int clockpin=8;
int latchpin=3;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(redled,OUTPUT); // declare the pinmode
  pinMode(greenled,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(servopin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigpin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echopin,INPUT);
  pinMode(datapin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockpin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchpin,OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(servopin); // declare servo object is connected to servo pin

}

int ping() // create a function {
  digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  digitalWrite(trigpin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);

  duration= pulseIn(echopin,HIGH);
  distance= duration*0.034/2; // distance is in cm
  return(distance);
  }

void loop() { 
  myservo.write(90); // set servo at 90 degree angle
  float value;
  value=ping(); // call the ping function
  Serial.println(value);
  delay(100);
  if(value>20) {
      digitalWrite(redled,LOW);
      digitalWrite(greenled,HIGH);

      digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
      shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B01010000); // move the car in forward direction
      digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
  }
  if(value<20&& value>15) {
      digitalWrite(redled,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(greenled,HIGH);

      digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
      shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B01010000);
      digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
  }
    if(value<15) {
      digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
      shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B00000000); // stop the car
      digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
      shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B00101000); // first back the robo car
      digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
      shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B00000000); // then again stop 
      digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
      delay(100);

      go(); // call go function
      delay(2000);
  }

  myservo.write(90);

}

void go() {
  int a;
  int b;
  myservo.write(0);
  delay(1000);
  a=ping();
  myservo.write(180);
  delay(1000);
  b=ping();

  if(a>b) {
   digitalWrite(redled,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);

   digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
   shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B00010000); // move to the right side
   digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);    
} else if(a<b) {
    digitalWrite(redled,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);

    digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
    shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B01000000); // move to the left side
    digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);     
} else if(a=b) {
    digitalWrite(redled,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);

    digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
    shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B00101000); // first back the robo car
    digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
    delay(4000); // wait for 4 seconds
    digitalWrite(latchpin,LOW);
    shiftOut(datapin,clockpin,LSBFIRST,B01000000); // then move to right direction
    digitalWrite(latchpin,HIGH);
    delay(2000); 
  }
}
```

The error in full is:

```
sketch_may02a:31:3: error: expected initializer before 'digitalWrite'

   digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);

   ^

sketch_may02a:32:20: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

   delayMicroseconds(10);

                    ^

sketch_may02a:34:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

   digitalWrite(trigpin,HIGH);

               ^

sketch_may02a:35:20: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

   delayMicroseconds(20);

                    ^

sketch_may02a:36:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

   digitalWrite(trigpin,LOW);

               ^

sketch_may02a:38:3: error: 'duration' does not name a type

   duration= pulseIn(echopin,HIGH);

   ^

sketch_may02a:39:3: error: 'distance' does not name a type

   distance= duration*0.034/2; // distance is in cm

   ^

sketch_may02a:40:3: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'

   return(distance);

   ^

sketch_may02a:41:3: error: expected declaration before '}' token

   }

   ^

exit status 1
expected initializer before 'digitalWrite'
```

Comment: In addition to that, why is your `ping` function declared with `int` return type? It looks like you intended to return `float` value. Although in your code you are constantly going back and forth on that.

Comment: **note:** you have repeating code in the `if` blocks in the `go()` function ..... the first three lines of each `if` block are same .... move the three lines to before the first `if` statement and delete them  from inside the three `if` blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function definition starts:

```
int ping() // create a function {
```

Notice that the comment is inserted **before** the open curly brace. That means the curly brace is commented out. Move the comment to the end of the line, or move the curly brace to a line on it's own.

Comment: Good catch. I looked at that code and saw what I expected to see, not what's there. (voted)